# cd /var/www/html/ error

Tags: directory, environment-variables

I am Trying to install angular4 but in the process I type this command:

```
cd /var/www/html/
```

As referred by the video but the error showing is this:

```
bash: cd: /var/www/html/: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 3):

`/var/www/html` is created when you install Apache HTTP server.

You can install Angular without Apache.

Check this out [How to install Angular](https://coursetro.com/posts/code/55/How-to-Install-an-Angular-4-App)

Comment: I Have install Tomcat Apache but it should be active at the time of Angular installation

Comment: @HarshalPulekar Tomcat Apache is for Java Servlets and JSPs,whereas you need Apache HTTP Server, you can use this link https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-16-04

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need Apache in order to use AngularJS. But I am presuming that whatever video you are following used the Apache Tomcat to serve the angular project.

Angular projects needs to be served by any server in order to get executed, after all its an web application right !! Usually people use node servers to serve the angular application because its easy and quick even new versions of Anuglar has CLI that has this capability in built.